# lookup table in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, lookup

I am trying to implement a kind of lookup table in MATLAB.

I have data generated from a script with three variables swept, let's say `var_a, var_b, var_c`. These are nested sweep, (`var_a` -> `var_b` -> `var_c`)
And there are 10 outputs, `out_01, out02, ..., out10`.

Now I have arranged the each output as `out_01 = f(var_a,var_b,var_c)`, i.e., simply rearranging the data similar to nested loop.

My question is, how can I build a lookup table for such data? 
I will give input like get `out_01` @ certain `var_a(X), var_b(Y), var_c(Z)`.

I have tried the following.

```
    idx1_var_a   = max(find(data.var_a <= options.var_a));
    idx2_var_a   = min(find(data.var_a >= options.var_a));

    idx1_var_b = max(find(data.var_b <= options.var_b));
    idx2_var_b = min(find(data.var_b >= options.var_b));

    idx1_var_c = max(find(data.var_c <= options.var_c));
    idx2_var_c = min(find(data.var_c >= options.var_c));

    Y1 = interpn(data.var_c,data.var_b,data.var_a,data.out_01,data.var_c(idx1_var_c),data.var_b(idx1_var_b),data.var_a(idx1_var_a))

    Y2 = interpn(data.var_c,data.var_b,data.var_a,data.out_01,data.var_c(idx2_var_c),data.var_b(idx2_var_b),data.var_a(idx2_var_a))        

    if Y1 == Y2
        Y = Y1
    else        
        Here I am unable to figure how to interpolate between these two output values,Y1, and Y2!!
    end
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Take a look at `interp1` - I think it is exactly what you need. Try it and update your answer if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: One way would be to use [Map](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/map-containers.html).

Comment: Thanks Floris, I was also thinking interp1 might work. It may be simple, can you point me to any example on how to use it? I have used interp1 for 1D data like this. interp1(var_a, out_01, X). To explain further, I want out_01 value to be output w.r.t var_a vector at a value of X, X can be part of var_a or else needs to interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

Suppose you have:

```
var_a = 1:3;
var_b = 0:0.3:0.9;
var_c = 1:2;

[A, B, C] = ndgrid(var_a, var_b, var_c)

F = A.^3+B.^2+C;
```

Now you can directly acces the function at all existing points:

```
F(1,2,2)
```

Or alternatively

```
F(var_a==1,var_b==0.3,var_c==2)
```

---

Now if you are interested in values between the gridpoints, you can use `interp3`

```
Vq = interp3(F,1.5,2.5,1.5)
```

Note that this takes the desired location in the vector as input.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for the input. I am not getting the out_01, out_02 etc from MATLAB but from a different software. But I am rearranging them in matlab.